# Bad array subscript error when trying to increment an associative array element

Tags: bash, associative-array

I can create an **associative array** and assign an integer to a key that contains a **single quote** in it:

```sh
$ declare -A dict
$ var="john's"
$ dict[$var]=1
$ echo ${dict[$var]}
1
$ declare -p dict
declare -A dict=(["john's"]="1" )
```

But when I try to increment its value:

```sh
$ (( dict[$var]++ ))
bash: ((: dict[john's]++ : bad array subscript (error token is "dict[john's]++ ")
$ (( dict["$var"]++ ))
bash: ((: dict[john's]++ : bad array subscript (error token is "dict[john's]++ ")
$ (( dict["${var}"]++ ))
bash: ((: dict[john's]++ : bad array subscript (error token is "dict[john's]++ ")
```

I always get the same error. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The single quote in `key` name is causing the parser to treat it as a un-terminated quote character. One way to fix this would be to escape the `'` character in the key

```
key="john's"
printf -v escKey "%q" "$key"
```

now because of the `%q` specifier, [`printf()`](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/printf) would have applied required escapes to all shell meta characters i.e. making it "shell-quoted" and re-usable. If you print the contents of `escKey` you'll notice the `'` escaped

```
printf '%s\n' "$escKey"
john\'s
```

Now you can use this keyname in your associative array. Remember you can always manually add the escapes which could be messy. Since `%q` is a native way provided by the shell, it is much safe to use it.

```
(( dict["$escKey"]++ ))
```

Also in `bash` versions >= 4.4 [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) has `@Q` which is a shortcut for `%q` specifier of `printf()` using which you can do

```
(( dict["${key@Q}"]++ ))
```

Comment: If you add the integer flag to the associative array with `declare -iA dict`, you can increment the entry with `dict[$var]+=1` without quoting/escaping the key. Escaping the key is only needed within arithmetic expressions. Nice to know the quirk.

Comment: Those `%q` / `${var@Q}` don't work for the values of `$var` for which bash resorts to the `$'...'` form of quoting. See my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to make sure, by escaping `$`, that `$var` isn't expanded until Bash starts parsing `dict[$var]++` as an arithmetic expression.

```
$ (( dict[\$var]++ ))
$ declare -p dict
declare -A dict=(["john's"]="2" )
```

---

On newer versions of Bash, enabling the `assoc_expand_once` shell option works too, but this is **unsafe** when keys are read from an untrusted source. An example of how even when this option is enabled the shell can still be tricked into executing arbitrary commands with a tainted `$var` is given in [Stephane's answer](/a/65578230).

Comment: I think I like that one best. I've added it to [How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/627474) on unix.SE. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, not only

```
(( dict[$var]++ ))
```

Won't work with some values of `$var`, but it's also an *arbitrary command execution* vulnerability.

```
bash-5.1$ var='1$(uname>&2)'
bash-5.1$ typeset -A dict
bash-5.1$ (( dict[$var]++ ))
Linux
Linux
```

Quoting the value of `$var` with `printf %q` or `${var@Q}` is not an option because with some values of `$var`, those operators use the `$'...'` form of quoting which is not understood in an arithmetic expression:

```
bash-5.1$ typeset -A dict
bash-5.1$ var=$(seq 2)
bash-5.1$ (( dict[${var@Q}]++ ))
bash-5.1$ echo "${!dict[@]}"
$1\n2
```

```
bash-5.1$ var=$'\n\'$(uname >&2)],x['
bash-5.1$ (( dict["${var@Q}"]++ ))
Linux
bash: ((: dict[$'\n\'$(uname >&2)],x[']++ : bad array subscript (error token is "x[']++ ")
```

(still an ACE).

Using the new (since 5.0) `assoc_expand_once` doesn't help as it still doesn't address the problem with the `@`/`*` values or the `]` character (and so doesn't fix the ACE vulnerabilities):

```
bash-5.1$ shopt -s assoc_expand_once
bash-5.1$ var='x],b[1$(uname>&2)'
bash-5.1$ typeset -A dict
bash-5.1$ (( dict[$var]++ ))
Linux
```

Another problem specific to `bash` (not `ksh93` nor `zsh`) is that bash associative arrays don't support the empty key, so you just can't use arbitrary strings as associative array keys. A work around is to prefix/suffix all your keys with a fixed string.

Here, you can do:

```
dict[.$var]=$(( ${dict[.$var]} + 1 ))
```

Or (assuming the `assoc_expand_once` option is **not** enabled):

```
let 'dict[.$var]++'
```

(make sure you use *single* quotes).

Here using `.` as the prefix.

See [How to use associative arrays safely inside arithmetic expressions?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/627474) for all the gory details and more caveats about that.

More generally, shell arithmetic expressions are a minefield. See also: [Security Implications of using unsanitized data in Shell Arithmetic evaluation](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/172103).